# Hatcher Exercise 2.1.26.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, geometric-topology

Given that $ X =[0, 1]$ and $A$ = {$\frac{1}{n} :n$ is any natural number} $\cup$ {$0$}. I want to show that $H_1(X, A)$ is not isomorphic to $H_1(X/A)$. Could you please help me with this problem?

My argument: The quotient space $X/A$ is basically the wedge of countably many circles, and hence its first homology group is the infinite direct sum of $Z$'s. On the other hand, the $X$ is contractible, and therefore, $H_1(X, A)$ is trivial. Is my argument good enough/correct? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks so much.

Comment: Hatcher wants to show that in general $H_*(X,A)$ and $\tilde{H}_*(X/A)$ are not isomorphic. In his example it is not easy to prove. A simpler example is $X$ = topologists's sine curve and $A$ = line segment at which $(x,\sin(1/x))$ clusters.

Comment: Thanks so much.

Comment: X/A is not actually a wedge sum (different topology forced by convergence to zero) and X contractible certainly does not imply (X;A) has zero relative homology

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your argument is not correct, for two reasons: first of all, $X/A$ is not exactly a wedge if countably many circles (this would not take into account the topology, the fact that $1/n\to 0$), and secondly $X$ is contractible does not imply $H_1(X,A) = 0$ : it implies $H_1(X) = 0$; but note that you have an exact sequence $H_1(X)\to H_1(X,A)\to H_0(A)\to H_0(X)$ so since $H_0(A)$ is very big and $H_0(X), H_1(X)$ are quite small, $H_1(X,A)$ has to be quite big (I'll let you give the precise statements for this)

What you want to do is actually compute $H_1(X,A)$ via this exact sequence (this is not too hard), and then identify $X/A$ more carefully. It should be closer to the Hawaiian earrings than a wedge of circles.

Comment: $X/A$ is in fact homeomorphic to the Hawaiin earring.

Comment: @PaulFrost : I thought so - I hadn't checked it in detail (and didn't want to) so I didn't want to claim it so affirmatively. Good to know my intuition isn't completely stupid !

Comment: Thanks again. I have seen the example of Hawaiin earring in Hatcher. Now, It's clear. Thanks again.

Answer (score 9):

The precise computation of $H_1(X/A)$ is not at all trivial. Luckily, we don't need to know much about $H_1(X/A)$ to complete this exercise.

In fact, the space $X/A$ is homeomorphic to the Hawaiian earring $H = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty C_n$, where $C_n = \{ z \in \mathbb C \mid \lvert z - \frac{1}{n} \rvert = \frac{1}{n} \}$ is the plane circle with center $\frac{1}{n} \in \mathbb R$ and radius $\frac{1}{n}$. In Hatcher's Example 1.25 $H$ is denoted as "The Shrinking Wedge of Circles". To see this, define $f : [0,1] \to H, f(t) = \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n}e^{(2n(n+1)t -1)\pi i}$ for $t  \in [\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n}]$ and $f(0) = 0$. This is easily seen to be a continuous surjection; the interval $[\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n}]$ is wrapped counterclockwise once around $C_n$ starting at the "cluster point" $0$. We have $f(A) = \{0 \}$, thus $f$ induces a continuous closed surjection $f' : X/A  \to H$. It is easy to see that $f'$ is injective, thus it is a homeomorphism.

The exact sequence $0 = H_1(X)  \to H_1(X,A) \to \widetilde{H}_0(A) \to \widetilde{H}_0(X) = 0$ shows that $H_1(X,A)$ is isomorphic to the free abelian group $\widetilde{H}_0(A)$ (which has countably many generators). That is, $\bigoplus_{n\in\Bbb N}\Bbb Z$ is a model for $\widetilde{H_0}(A)$ (and also $H_0(A)$) and thus for $H_1(X,A)$.

It is shown in Hatcher's book that the first homology is the Abelianisation of the first fundamental group. It is also shown by Hatcher (alternatively make reference to the end of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3928674) answer) that there is a surjective homomorphism $F:\pi_1(H)\to\prod_{n\in\Bbb N}\Bbb Z$. By the universal property of Abelianisation (quotient property) there is a unique homomorphism $G:H_1(H)\to\prod_{n\in\Bbb N}\Bbb Z$ such that $Gh=F$, where $h:\pi_1(X)\to H_1(H)$ is the canonical map. The surjectivity of $F$ implies surjectivity of $G$, and (relying on the axiom of choice, if you care about that kind of thing) it follows $H_1(H)$ is uncountable.

However, $\bigoplus_{n\in\Bbb N}\Bbb Z$ is countable; it is the countable union of the countable subgroups $\bigoplus_{n=1}^k\Bbb Z$, $k=1,2,\cdots$. Since $H_1(H)\cong H_1(X,A)$ would imply $H_1(H)\cong H_1(X,A)\cong\bigoplus_{n\in\Bbb N}\Bbb Z$ and we know this is impossible (left hand side is uncountable, right hand side is countable) it follows $H_1(H)$ cannot be isomorphic to $H_1(X,A)$, completing the exercise.

Note we did not need any algebraic observations here, this is purely set-theoretic; for instance, $\Bbb Z$ and $\Bbb Z^2$ have the same cardinality so you need some algebraic observations to include they are not isomorphic as groups.

---

The computation of $H_1(H)$ is difficult. See [this](https://web.math.rochester.edu/people/faculty/doug/otherpapers/eda-kawamura2.pdf), for instance. For an overkill method to conclude $H_1(H)\not\cong H_1(X,A)$ using this computation, you can note that $H_1(H)$ is not free Abelian whereas $H_1(X,A)$ is.

**Acknowledgement.** The proof that $H_1(H)$ is uncountable, and therefore not isomorphic to $H_1(X,A)$, is due to FShrike.

Comment: Thank you so much. This answer is really beautiful. Thanks again.

Comment: @FShrike You should make an edit to my answer. Alternatively write a question (Is $H_1(H)$ isomorphic to $\bigoplus_n \mathbb Z$?) and answer it. You can invoke https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3925195.

Comment: @PaulFrost I have made an edit. I hope it is acceptable

Comment: @FShrike Surely it is acceptable!